# Разрезать прямоугольник на квадраты и вывести список с размерами сторон

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

На вход функции подается длина и ширина прямоугольника, нужно разрезать его на квадраты и вывести список с размерами сторон этих квадратов. Если исходная длина и ширина равны, вывести 0. Подскажите алгоритм пожалуйста.

Пример вход **rect(5,3)**, выход **[3,2,1,1]**

Визуализация:

```
x x x x x      x x x     x x
x x x x x  ->  x x x  +  x x  +  x  +  x
x x x x x      x x x
```

Comment: Очень простой рекурсивный алгоритм, с чем возникли трудности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем минимальный из двух размеров и выводим его. Затем уменьшаем максимальный размер на минимальный и начинаем сначала. Продолжаем пока один из размеров не станет равен нулю.

```
(5, 3): Выводим 3. Вычитаем и получаем (2, 3)
(2, 3): Выводим 2. Вычитаем и получаем (2, 1)
(2, 1): Выводим 1. Вычитаем и получаем (1, 1)
(1, 1): Выводим 1. Вычитаем и получаем (1, 0)
(1, 0): Стоп
```

Неясно только, почему дано такое неестественное требование "если исходная длина и ширина равны, вывести 0". Логично было бы просто вывести длину - тогда бы этот случай подпадал под общий алгоритм.

Comment: благодарю, тупил немного, на площадь ориентировался)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input("Длина:  "))
b = int(input("Ширина: "))

area = a * b

def to_quadrats(area):
    if area == 0:
        raise StopIteration
    while(area):
        for i in range(area, 0, -1):
            if i * i <= area:
                area -= i * i
                yield i
                break
        to_quadrats(area)

result = list(to_quadrats(area))
print(result)
```

---

Объяснение:

Проблема решена за помощи *итератора* - рекурсивная функция `def to_quadrats()` при каждом запросе о последующее значение выдает его командой `yield i` (и затем приостановится и ждёт на последующий запрос).

Сам запрос о *последующее и последующее* значения итератора (пока он не исчерпается) реализуется функцией `list()`.

В сикле

```
for i in range(area, 0, -1):
```

мы ищем самое большое значение (сторону квадрата), для которого его вторая степень (площадь квадрата) *ещё не превышает текущую площадь* - да, вместо `area` бы лучше было взять его квадратный корень.

После нахождения такого значения текущая площадь соответственно уменьшится, самое значение выдастся командой `yield` и цикл `for` прекращается командой `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Фигуры удобно представить массивами: `x x x` - `[1, 1, 1]`. Получается работаем с матрицами.

```
def f(matrix, res=[]):
    if bool(matrix):
        line = min(len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))
        if len(matrix) == len(matrix[0]):
            res.append(line)
        else:
            res.append(line)
            f([y[line:] for y in matrix], res) if len(matrix) < len(matrix[0]) else f([y for y in matrix[line:]], res)
    return res

print f([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
# [3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Как-то сложно... Вы не обфускатором работаете? Функция ``size(matrix)`` возвращает то просто две переменных, то кортеж. К тому же громоздкая, ее можно в пару строк написать. На другие функции даже смотреть не хочется.

Comment: насчёт return, попробуйте в консоли `t = 1,1; print type(t)`. Вашу пару строк в студию, а я поправлю.

Comment: ``m = min(len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))``,  ``return (m,m)``

Comment: Или даже вообще ``return min(len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))``, потому что какой смысл возвращать два значения, если они одинаковые? Достаточно и одного.

Comment: спасибо - поменял

Answer (score 0):

```
length = int(input("Длина:  "))
width  = int(input("Ширина: "))

result = []

while(length > 0):
    if length < width:
        length, width = width, length
    result.append(width)
    length -= width

print(result)
```

Меньшую страницу прибавим в результат, затем длиннейшую сократим о неё, и этот процесс продолжаем, пока не получим нуль.

Comment: Когда этот мой ответ рабочий, вы можете его оценить.